# Why won't MySQL let me remove attribute "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1293

I have a table with two timestamp fields. I simply defined them with a name and the type `TIMESTAMP`, yet for some reason MySQL automatically set one of them with a default value and the attribute `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I was planning on having NO default value in either of the fields, but one of the fields is called "date_updated" so I suppose I could set the mentioned attribute to that field.

Unfortunately, it's the field "date_created" that was set with the `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute, and no matter what I do, MySQL won't let me remove it.

I've tried editing the "date_created" field and removing the attribute. When clicking save, the attribute is back. I have also tried selecting both fields, removing the attribute from one of them and setting it on the other. It gives me the error `#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause` and suddenly both attribute columns on the values are set to `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` the result:

```
Error
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `pages` CHANGE  `date_created`  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
CHANGE  `date_updated`  `date_updated` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL

MySQL said: 

#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

Must I really recreate both those columns in the correct order to fix this?

I would like to know how I could solve this problem correctly, for future reference.

Thanks

---

Now I've also tried to run

```
ALTER TABLE pages
CHANGE date_created
 date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should specify **`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`** (or `DEFAULT 0`)

```
ALTER TABLE pages CHANGE date_created date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
CHANGE  `date_updated`  `date_updated` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is DEFAULT NULL an option too?

Comment: @GolezTrol nope, since it's defined as `NOT NULL` it can't be NULL

Comment: Does it always need a default? For NOT NULL timestamp types I mean. I'm having the same problem but I can't remove the default.

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL version 5.6.6, you can use the ***explicit_defaults_for_timestamp*** option in the configuration file, therefore timestamp columns will not have 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' or 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' attributes by default. It will also be possible so set these columns to NULL if they are not declared as NOT NULL.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp