# SqlAlchemy TIMESTAMP 'on update' extra

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sql-timestamp

I am using SqlAlchemy on python3.4.3 to manage a MySQL database. I was creating a table with:

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, text, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import BIGINT
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
class MyClass(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'my_class'

  id = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
  created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
  updated_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
  param1 = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True), server_default=text('0'), nullable=False)
```

when I create this table with:

```
engine = create_engine('{dialect}://{user}:{password}@{host}/{name}'.format(**utils.config['db']))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I get:

```
mysql> describe my_class;
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| created_at     | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                           |
| updated_at     | timestamp           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| param1         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
```

Now the problem is that I do not want any on_update server default on my `created_at` attribute, its purpose is, in fact, being written only at the creation of the record, not on every update, as stated in the declaration of the class.

From a couple of tests I have made, I noticed that if I insert another attribute of type `TIMESTAMP` before `created_at`, then this attribute gets the `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` extra, while `created_at` does not, as desired. This suggests that the first `TIMESTAMP` attribute SqlAlchemy finds in the declaration of a mapping gets the `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` extra, though I don't see any reason for such behaviour.

I have also tried:

```
created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.utcnow, server_onupdate=None, nullable=False)
```

and

```
created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.utcnow, server_onupdate=text(''), nullable=False)
```

but the problem persists.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the problem is not related with SqlAlchemy but with the underlying MySQL engine. The default behaviour is to set `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the first TIMESTAMP column in a table.

This behaviour is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp). As far as I understand, a possible solution is to start MySQL with the `--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=FALSE` flag. Another solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126546). I haven't tried either solution yet, I will update this answer as soon as I solve the problem.

EDIT: I tried the second method and it is not very handy but it works. In my case I created a set of the tables which do not have a `created_at` attribute and then I have altered all the remaining tables as described in the link above.

Something along the lines of:

```
_no_alter = set(['tables', 'which', 'do not', 'have', 'a created_at', 'column'])
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
for table in Base.metadata.tables.keys():
    if table not in _no_alter:
      engine.execute(text('ALTER TABLE {} MODIFY created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0'.format(table)))
```

EDIT2: another (easier) way to accomplish this is by setting in SqlAlchemy a `server_default` value for the column:

```
created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False, server_default=text('0'))
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced same issue, you can accomplish this by:

```
created_time   = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
updated_time   = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```